# Nonstatespace Form ARMA Estimation Procedure

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, arima

Consider the following *observed* stochastic process $\{y_0,y_2,..,y_T\}$ governed by the equation,

$$y_t= \phi_1 y_{t-1} +\theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} +\tilde{ \epsilon}_t$$

Where $\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

If I want to estimate the paramters $\theta=(\phi_1,\theta_1,\sigma^2)$

The likelihood of observing the data of $(y_0,y_1,y_2...,y_T)$ can be rewriten as that of joing probability of observing the random shocks $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2...,\epsilon_T)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(y_1,y_2,..,y_t|\theta) &=& \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon_t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \\
&=& \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_t- \phi_1 y_{t-1} -\theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \\
&=& \Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \Bigg)^T \exp\left(-\frac{(y_1- \phi_1 y_{0} -\theta_1 \epsilon_{0})^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(y_2- \phi_1 y_{1} -\theta_1 \epsilon_{1})^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\ \cdot \cdot \cdot \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Problem is we don't observe the shocks $\epsilon$.

**Is this a correct estimation procedure?**

Assume $\epsilon_{1}=0$ and calculate $\epsilon^*_{1}=y_1- \phi_1 y_{0} -\theta_1 \epsilon_{0}$

Then using the value for $\epsilon_{1}$ solve for $\epsilon^*_{2}=y_2- \phi_2 y_{1} -\theta_2 \epsilon^*_{1}$

...

And so on and so forth recursively solving for $(\epsilon^*_1,\epsilon^*_2...,\epsilon^*_T)$ as only a function of the paramters $\theta$.

**Question:** Is this a valid estimation procedure? Most of the literature I have seen on ARMA estimation has been to represent the MLE in statespace and of the MLE form of $(y_0,y_1,y_2...,y_T)$. The estimation procedure I am using is similar to that of estimating an MA model.

Comment: Your method reminds me of *conditional maximum likelihood* in the literature, as you condition on the first value being zero. There is also the *full maximum likelihood* method where the first value is estimated.

Comment: So this is a correct estimation procedure?